# ios objective-c tableView searchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a hidden searchBar in a tableView header:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
    self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
}
```

I also have a magnifying-glass icon button that reveals the search bar:

```
- (IBAction)showSearchBar:(id)sender {
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Problem is, when I pull down the table (to reload data) - it also shows the search bar.

I only want the searchBar to become visible when the magnifying-glass icon gets tapped.

I am not really sure, how to address this problem?

Am I hiding it the wrong way in the first place?

Thanks,

Added a screenshot to make my question more clear:
[searchbar appears when pulling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28xaQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't tried that out, but I can image that you just have to hide it. for example:
`[[self.searchDisplayController view] setHidden:YES]`

Comment: Yes,

Switching self.searchBar.hidden = true and false in few places made the difference I was looking for.

Thanks,